# Do I have to pay tax for contracting work in US

Tags: contracts, taxes

I'm from Vietnam and a vietnamese citizen. A startup in the US wants to contract me for 50 hours of work. They gave me an IRS form and suggested I fill it out. The form name **w-9**

So I have 3 questions here.

1. Do I have to fill out the form?
2. If I filled the form, does that mean I will have to pay tax?
3. How much tax would I have to pay? Like 40% of what the start-up pays me?

Comment: What form? And what's their rationale for asking you to fill it out? You might need to ask them directly.

Comment: They are not sure about tax and things either, they just know that they are start up and they need to comply with such things, so they do it regardless

Comment: Sounds like *someone* should be speaking (or hiring) an accountant familiar with foreign contractors. Being a "start up" is no excuse for doing things haphazardly.

Comment: For some reason the 'edit' doesn't work for me so I'm commenting.  The title does not represent the question properly.  The title should be 'how do I' not 'Do I have to'.  If the title remains 'Do I have to' then my answer would be 'if you know a place in the world where they don't pay taxes do let me know.'

Comment: There's a difference between 'do i need to pay taxes' and 'do i need to pay taxes in the US if I live in vietnam', the latter is the case here and that is valid question.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the current tax agreement between the USA and Vietnam](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/tax-policy/treaties/Documents/Treaty-Vietnam-7-7-2015.pdf)

Read article 14. It says that you pay tax in Vietnam if you live there, unless you spend a portion of time based in the USA.